# hide background images for particular div

Tags: html, asp.net, css, background-image, background-process

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 40px; background-image:url('images/newhom/_Menu_Bg.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x " align="center">       
          <div style="width: 1260px" align="center">         
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height: 40px;">                 
                        <tr>             
                              <td >                   
                                   1) home                                 
                              </td>                      
                               <td>             
                                   2) about us                
                                </td>
                                 <td>              
                                       ....      
                                 </td>
                         </tr>
                  </table>
          </div>
 </div>
```

i'd like to hide the background images for the div style="width: 1260px>.

pls give me some solution for this,

Comment: Give it a background colour and it will blot out the image behind

Comment: Can't you just not include the background image? Or are you trying to do this dynamically? Do you want to show it some timess and not other times? If so, what is the criteria?

Comment: @Zeeju Sam Hood is right just give it a background-color see here an example fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/nA3sX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a background color

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 40px; background-image:url('images/newhom/_Menu_Bg.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x " align="center">       
          <div style="width: 1260px; background-color: #fff;" align="center">         
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height: 40px;">                 
                        <tr>             
                              <td >                   
                                   1) home                                 
                              </td>                      
                               <td>             
                                   2) about us                
                                </td>
                                 <td>              
                                       ....      
                                 </td>
                         </tr>
                  </table>
          </div>
 </div>
```